# How to retrieve results from a search from several pages

Tags: javascript

I am need to collect data from a website that allows me to download the results of a query but only the ones currently being displayed on that page.

I have no experience whatsoever with javascript or even any real programming. A friend told me that I might be able to do it with the "Custom JavaScript for websites" Addon for Chrome.

I managed to get it to download the file I want for each page using:

```
document.getElementById('dContent').value = 'full';
document.getElementById('submit-download').click();
```

I still need to manually change to the next page. I tried to do this automatically by adding a cycle:

```
for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
location.href='https://www.myurl.com/search?query=keyword&page=' +i;
document.getElementById('dContent').value = 'full';
document.getElementById('submit-download').click();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work*. My google skills and limited knowledge only took me this far. Am I doing something wrong? I wonder if the addon actually allows this as I reckon it might not work as a new page is being loaded. Is there another software that I might use for this purpose?

Thank you in advance for your help.

- - the url for the queries follows the page=1 / =2 / ... rule for the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('dContent').value = 'full';
  document.getElementById('submit-download').click();

  var page = parseInt(location.search.match(/\d\d?$/)[0])

  if(!isNaN(page) && page < 20){
    location.href='https://www.myurl.com/search?query=keyword&page=' +(page + 1);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be working but I reckon it is too fast to download the file each page. Is there a way to add some sort of wait between the cycle?

Comment: I've edited  my answer to delay 1000 ms, but if you have to wait until the file is downloaded before moving on, there's probably a better way, like an event for when the file is downloaded.

Comment: thanks for the update Chad. It just seems to download the documents on the last page (the one I set for limit of 'page'). Even when I set a wait time of 10000ms. Is there a simple way to simply check for the file being downloaded event? That would probably be the best as you mentioned. I could only find solutions on the server side. Thanks once more for your help!

Comment: If you're using an addon, there might be an event Chrome gives you to listen for a completed download. I'm not familiar with add-ons at all.